# Angular - Router navigate canceled without reason

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-routing

I have an angular (4.2.5) app, and at some point in my code, I do this :

```
this._appService
    .post('/createhero/save', opts)
    .subscribe(
        (resData: any) => 
        {   
            this._router.navigate(['home']);
        }
    );
```

The router call to `navigate()` doesn't work - nothing happens. I enabled route debug, and this is what I get :

[image: Error]

So the navigation is canceled without given reason. In others components, I have the same kind of `navigate()` (some in observable callbacks too) which works well. The route `/home` works as well.

I'm starting to run out of ideas, and I don't even know why the `navigate()` won't work in this case.

Comment: Where did you use your navigate code?

Comment: In my CreateHeroComponent save() method, which is triggered by a button `<button (click)="save()">Done</button>`

Comment: For me, the issue was coming from a guard as well (the `MsalGuard` one from `@azure/msal-angular@2.0.5`) and was only occurring at initial navigation on small-name routes like "/foo" (a bug from `@azure/msal-angular`; in particular, the problem disappeared by renaming the route to "/foo-bar-baz")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Had similar issue, `reason` really doesn't help does it :)

What my issue was, was that the route I tried to navigate had a guard on its own which subscribed to observable and since I already gave value to it, the initial value of observable was `false` and since route was blocked, navigation was canceled.

Can it be that some other guard is blocking the route and `canActivate()` gives out `true`/`false` while depending on your query result but not actually waiting for the result?

Hope this helps a bit at debugging :)

Comment: I had a child route that had a stricter level guarding it that helped me out. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Guys i have a similar issue ,how did you resolve that?